# Achieving indirect addressing while only using absolute(direct) addressing

Tags: assembly, mips

For example, how can I achieve something like this:

```
lw RegisterDestination, (RegisterSource)
```

with absolute addressing?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question entirely. There's not absolute addressing mode for `lw` on MIPS, unless you mean something like `lw $somereg,offset($zero)`, in which case you'd only be able to address the top and bottom 32kB of memory. Could you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes sure, im sorry if I was unclear. The Question is how I can realise an indirect addressing like (Rdest := Mem[Mem[Rsrc]]) without actually using an indirect addressing, but instead use absolute adressing (Rdest := Mem[Rsrc] which should mimic an indirect addressing.

So basically the task is to implement the features of indirect adressing while only using absolute adressing to do so.

Comment: Rtemp = Mem[Rsrc]; Rdest = Mem[Rtemp] ?

Comment: This was my idea as well, but it is not possible to use load word without indirect addressing. Is there a way to implement what you wrote with some command which allows absolute addressing? For example  "lw $t0, $t1"  is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

MIPS load and store instructions (e.g. `lb`, `lw`, `sb`, `sw`) take the memory address only as a combination of a constant and a register value and they perform only one memory access, they don't first obtain an address from memory and then read or write memory at that address. They read or write at the specified address that's `some constant + some register's value`.

If you need to do two memory accesses, you must use two load/store instructions.

If you're concerned about the source code size, you could probably wrap several instructions into a macro and use that macro instead. But that's assembler-specific.